# Roblox Error: attempt to index nil with 'TextLabel'

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a fighting game with a GUI in Roblox Studio and this simple script to make one of the menus show up is having the error

> attempt to index nil with 'TextLabel'

This is my script:

```
local FightButton = script.Parent
local ButtonsGui = script.Parent.Parent
local FightGui = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui:FindFirstChild("FightGui")

FightButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    ButtonsGui.Enabled = false
    FightGui.Enabled = true
end)
```

Also, the FightButton isn't underneath FightGui.

Comment: I don't believe either of the errors you've shared come from this script

Comment: Sorry! The error in the title is wrong. I was trying to use textlabels instead of screengui and it still didn't work (and yes I made it visible instead of enabled) but I copied the wrong error to the title

Comment: Also this is the only script in the game that involves gui, and the error refrences this script in the output box when I playtest